# iterating through an array containing two elements results in three objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to iterate through an array and clone and append an element to a div element for each item in the array.
Everything is working except when it's more than one element I get some unexpected results.
The array contains two element's and I've checked that the each loop only runs two times, but for some reason I get a third element in the result.

Am I using *clone()* and *appendTo()* correctly?

[image]

**each loop**:

```
let items = $(contentWrap).find(".lc-rating-modal-review-items-wrap");
$(items).empty();

$.each(data.items, function (index, review) {
    let item = GenerateReviewItem(review);
    $(item).appendTo(items);
});
```

**GenerateReviewItem**:

```
function GenerateReviewItem(review) {
    let result = $(wrap).find(".lc-rating-review-item-template").clone();

    $(result).find(".lc-rating-review-item-template-date").html(review.dateFormated);
    $(result).find(".lc-rating-review-item-body-wrap").html(review.review);
    $(result).find(".lc-rating-review-item-template-stars-rating-label").html("(" + review.rating + ")");

    $(result).find(".lc-rating-review-item-template-star").each(function (index, star) {
        if (review.rating >= (index + 1)) {
            $(star).removeClass("fa-star-o").addClass("fa-star");
        }
    });              

    return result;
}
```

**Html to clone**:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div class="lc-rating-review-item-template">
        <div class="lc-rating-review-item-header-wrap">
            <div class="lc-rating-review-item-template-stars-wrap">
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o lc-rating-review-item-template-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o lc-rating-review-item-template-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o lc-rating-review-item-template-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o lc-rating-review-item-template-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o lc-rating-review-item-template-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="lc-rating-review-item-template-stars-rating-label"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <span class="lc-rating-review-item-template-date"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lc-rating-review-item-body-wrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not modify the array you are looping through. It can cause some weird side effects, like the one you are having.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean.. I don't modify the array, I only loop through and adds an element to a div for each element in the array. Or that's at least what I'm trying to do

Comment: The only wrong thing I can find is that you are doble wrapping your `item` and `items` jQuery objects, but I don't think that's the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend storing the reference to your template node outside of your loop, and then doing the cloning inside of the loop.

Define this outside the loop:

`let template = $(wrap).find(".lc-rating-review-item-template")`

And then change this:

`let result = $(wrap).find(".lc-rating-review-item-template").clone();`

To this:

`let result = template.clone();`

---

As it is currently, when your loop executes a second time, `$(wrap).find(".lc-rating-review-item-template")` is likely finding two items instead of one.

It also appears that `wrap`, unless it is a global, is undefined within the context of the `GenerateReviewItem(review)` function.